# Delete a single file from browser cache

Tags: browser-cache

i have an image in my page, the image is cached in the browser.

now i have deleted the image, however Because it was cached, the request does not go to the server, And it appears again.

so How can I delete it from the browser cache?

Comment: You want to force the end user's browser to re-download an asset?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you cannot physically delete cached file. Instead you can generate link to the file dynamically, for example

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write('<img id="without-cache" src="image.jpg?v=' + new Date().getTime() + '" />');
</script>
```

and eventually change the source with different `?v=` when you want to reload it without loading it from cache.

```
$("#without-cache").attr("src", "image.jpg?v=" + new Date().getTime());
```